# How can I find the correct image path in CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: My workspace on VS Code]

I am trying to access the first picture in the img folder but I can't seem to get the right file directory. I've tried it with `../img/model-1.jpg`, with `/img/mode1-1.jpg`, and without the img. I've tried the to copy the path as well but nothing seems to work. I don't know if I'm doing it wrong or is it a glitch.

Comment: Please provide the part of your html where you include the css. Also screenshots of code are not ideal, as others cannot copy parts of it into their answers but would have to type everything themselves.

Comment: `../img/model-1.jpg` should have worked for you. In your compiled CSS (main.css) what is the path?

Comment: @disinfor, my path CSS path is <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

Comment: @TadWohlrapp, thanks for the information. The path to my CSS is <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

Comment: This is a guessing game. Try `./img/model-1.jpg`
Also adding the information in the original question instead of comments is preferred.

Comment: @TadWohlrapp I've tried that combination and anyone that I could think off. I don't know if it's maybe the settings or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. I was using background-image and it was only focusing on the url and the other text probably cancelled it out. I used background and the link path worked fine. Thanks for all of your help!